# How to prevent TOpenDialog from changing the current working directory for the relative path to a file?

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl

I use `TOpenDialog` to choose a file to open, and want to specify a folder with the `InitialDir` property:

```
FILE* fp;
OpenDialog1->InitialDir= "../data"; 

if (OpenDialog1->Execute())
{
  fp=fopen(OpenDialog1->FileName.c_str(),"r");
  ...
  fclose(fp);
}
```

But, when I then use a relative path to open another file, I see that the relative path changed to the folder selected with `TOpenDialog`. But I don't want `TOpenDialog` to affect the relative path.

```
fp=fopen("AnotherFile.txt","r"); //looks in folder "data"
...
fclose(fp)
```

Is there any way to prevent `TOpenDialog` from changing the current working path, or is the only way to save the path and then restore it?

Comment: I workaround this problem by using both absolute and relative paths ... after obtaining absolute path from dialog or whatever I scan if it is compatible with my relative path and if it is I convert it to such but if it is not absolute path is used ... If you do not want to change path at all then use `TFileList` from win3.11  components instead ...

Answer (score 0):

The dialog changes the current working directory while browsing around. That is working as designed, you can't prevent it.

However, you can restore the original current working directory when the dialog is closed by enabling the `ofNoChangeDir` flag in its `Options` property:

> After the user clicks OK, resets the current directory to whatever it was before the file-selection dialog opened.

Though, you really should not be relying on relative file paths in the first place.  Always open files using absolute file paths.